# Implicit differentiation in terms of $y$ or $x$?!

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation, tangent-line

> If I am doing an implicit differentiation in a curve in $\Bbb R^2$ for example, because I want to get the tangent line on a certain point... How am I suposed to know if I should differentiate it in terms of $Y$, or in terms of $X$?

Am I going to get two slopes, one that's perpendicular to the other one by changing the term that I am doing that differentiation? If so, how can I guarantee that the term choosed to differentiate will give me the slope for the tangent?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent question, and it may be worth looking up the implicit function theorem for a full answer, i.e. when can you actually solve for an explicit function of $y$ or of $x$ given some implicit function $f(x,y)=0$.

However, in general in Calculus, you have a function of the form $y(x)$ implicitly defined. Meaning you have some curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the form $f(x,y)=c$, but you care about solving for the rate of change of $y$ which depends on the variable $x$, which you take to be independent.